# Logarithmic equation $\log n\le10^6$

Tags: algorithms, logarithms

I'm trying to solve logarithmic equation (instance below).

$\log{n}\le10^6$

Solution is:

$\log{n}\le10^6\rightarrow2^{\log{n}}\le2^{10^6}\rightarrow n\le2^{10^6}$.

I have no idea how author get this solution. This mean there have a property like $x^{\log{n}}=n$? And how solve this with using real log properties?

*Source* `Row 1` https://udel.edu/~caviness/Class/CISC320-02S/exercise-solns/ch01/R-1.7.pdf

Comment: By the way, use **\log n** to generate $\log n$ and **\ge** or **\geq** to generate $\geq$. If you wanted, you could also use **\geqslant** to generate $\geqslant$, the same applying with **\leqslant** to generate $\leqslant$

Comment: The author must have meant the binary logarithm ($\log_2$)... and $a^{\log_a x}=x$ for all $a>1$ and $x>0$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Well ok then.

Comment: @Triatticus Actually the condition $b\neq 1$ is needed.

Comment: You can also use \rightarrow to get $\rightarrow$ and \Rightarrow to get $\Rightarrow$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\log(n) \le 10^6$$

From the elementary property of the exponential-logarithm we have that

$$\large b^{\log_b(x)} = x ~~~~~~~~~~~ \text{for} ~~~ x > 0;\ ~~ b > 0,\ ~~ b\neq 1$$

From what I understand, your "book" or whatever, uses the ugly notation $\log$ to indicate $\log_2$, the binary logarithm, that is, base $2$.

Besides the ugliness, we exponentiate in base $2$ then:

$$\large 2^{\log_2(n)} \leq 2^{10^6}$$

$$n \leq 2^{10^6}$$

Which provides the result you were searching for.

Answer (score 2):

Note that **by definition**

$$c=\log_a b \iff a^c=b$$

thus

$$a^{\log_a b}=b$$

morover since logarithmic function is an **increasing function** we have that

$$\log_a x\le \log_a y \iff x  \le y$$

thus

$$\log_2 n\le 10^6 = \log_2 2^{10^6} \iff n \le 2^{10^6}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\log_a(n)<10^6$$
But we can use that $10^6=\log_a\left(a^{10^6}\right)$:
$$\log_a(n)<\log_a\left(a^{10^6}\right)$$
For $a>1$ the $\log_a$ is increasing, so:
$$n<a^{10^6}$$
For $a<1$ the $\log_a$ is decreasing, so:
$$n>a^{10^6}$$